# Does my acer swift 3 (SF314-54-34R2) have HDMI 2.0?

Tags: hdmi

Does my acer swift 3 (SF314-54-34R2) have HDMI 2.0?

I found out, that it has Intel® UHD Graphics 620 so the HDMI should be limited to 1.4 but some of the reviews say it has HDMI 2.0.

In case it has only 1.4, will it run on HDMI 2.0 cabel and are there any benefits running a 2.0 HDMI cabel if its limited to 1.4 HDMI?

Answer (score 0):

The Intel 620 also has DisplayPort 4k @ 60Hz, so with appropriate (active) DisplayPort to HDMI conversion built into the motherboard it would be effectively capable of HDMI 2.0.

The HDMI support of the graphics itself (1.4) does not rule out using one of the other faster interfaces to drive a converter.

What your system is specifically capable of should match what your manufacturer states, otherwise it would open them up to false advertising claims.

As to the cable using a 2.0 cable should be fine for everything up to 2.0. Running 1.4 over it shouldn't be a problem, and you have a cable that you can continue to use when you do finally get 2.0. It shouldn't matter what earlier version of HDMI you have, it will be backwards compatible. The benefit is that (in theory) you have a slightly better quality cable that is guaranteed to work on 2.0 as well as 1.4. I'm most cases the cost difference is negligible.

The easiest way to find out is to try it.

Comment: Damn, you are quick (and accurate)! Thanks a lot! I've never heard of this site before and it really suprised me in the best way :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! You are very welcome and I hope you can hang around to contribute more good questions and hopefully answers too. :) There are a lot of sites in our network with topics ranging from programming to cookery and beyond so hopefully we can help you in other ways: https://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: @Stepan back to your original question though, there are cases where suppliers have added HDMI 2.0 to distinguish features across a range of machines. In [another one of my answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1475282/intel-hd-graphics-620-does-my-display-adapter-support-hdmi-2-0-necessary-for-a) I mention that a midrange laptop had HDMI 1.4 while a higher end one has HDMI 2.0 on the spec sheet and it is a matter of extra design time and cost to implement it, both machines use the same graphics so the only way it could happen is to convert it from DisplayPort.

Comment: Thx :) ... I am a lawyer and have (almost) no knowledge of technics so I translated your answer - buy hdmi 2.0 cabel, it will run on your Acer, price difference is not that big. ... maybe it will be 2.0 maybe not :)